# Как «скинуть» кеширование страниц после ребилда?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

После ребилда сайта у "старых" пользователей остается старая версия сайта. Если перейти на любую страницу (не главную) и обновить ее - "сайт обновляется". Но если человек повторно заходит на ГЛАВНУЮ страницу, получает старую версию сайта. Из-за этого возникают некоторые неловкие моменты с авторизацией. Разумеется решать эту проблему рассказывая всем, что нужно перейти на любую страницу кроме главной и обновить ее, после авторизироваться, бредово... Открывать консоль разработчика - application - clear site data никто тоже делать не будет (хотя это помогает решить вопрос).

Собственно какие пути решения данного вопроса. (стоит PWA модуль, ну это и так понятно, с ним и связано...да?!).

Comment: при ребилдах у всех ассетсов(js/css/fonts/pics), которые были изменены, нужно менять url их источников.

Comment: Привет. В nuxt.config у меня build: {
    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : `[contenthash].js`,
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].js' : `[contenthash].js`,
      css: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].css' : `[contenthash].css`
    } }  Я предполагаю что это сервис воркер кеширует главную страницу. Файл sw.js я не трогал, он дефолтный. Пс. как тут вообще форматирование кода делать))) Даже переноса строки нет...

Comment: Вся информация должна быть в вопросе, под вопросом есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1301154/edit)